# Must I use Libraries In C#

Tags: c#

I'm just starting out to learn C# with Begin to Code with C# by Rob Myles.

The first thing I note is that he uses a snapsengine libraries to execute any instruction like displaying output . makes me wonder what is actually happening under the hood.

for example

```
{
 public void StartProgram()
 {
SnapsEngine.SetTitleString("Begin to Code With C#");
SnapsEngine.DisplayString("Welcome to the world of Snaps");
 }
}
```

I want to be able to display an out put without using a library, then advance to writing my own libraries.

is this how C# is designed to work? Is there a reference for all the libraries?

Please help a beginner

Comment: "without using a library" What does that mean? Even without the .NET-framework SDK? What exactly is your task? Also what kind of app is this? Console-application? WonForms? WPF? UWP? ASP.NET?...?

Comment: I think the bigger question is why a learning C# book is promoting an unnecessary 3rd party (or is it the author's?) library.  Now you have _two_ things to learn.   I recommend another book, one that sticks to Microsoft only and not one that arguably should be called _Begin to Code `Snaps` with C#_

Comment: @MickyD Can you recommend one please? One that is Beginner Friendly

Comment: @HimBromBeere Well maybe a console app first, I am an absolute beginner, But I'm intermediate with PowerShell. my final aim is to design a Desktop Attendance Check in App. For now, I just want to read input, manipulate the date and have my computer return output. maybe on a console. You can also do well to tell me how these apps differ from each other in terms of final output. Thanks alot

Comment: "must I use libraries?" no, because eventually, you'll be able to write code that does what these libraries do. It'll take a lot of time though until you can, and even then it'll take a long time to write each library equivalent. Should you use libraries to learn about coding? I don't see what's wrong with that. Coding is not exclusively about low-level mechanisms, but also about abstraction and composition. Learning this early on is not a mistake. It's good to understand what a pointer is, but I haven't used pointers explicity for many years now and that's a good thing.

Comment: https://beta.iop.org/sites/default/files/2019-07/teaching-programming.pdf talks about why this individual teaches in this way.

Comment: Victor, not off-hand but I would suggest you checking out say Amazon, finding an older, more established and popular learning-C# book.  Read the description carefully.  Perhaps an old C# .NET Framework 2 book.  Then once you've picked up the basics, get a newer book that covers C# 6+.  Sometimes the newer books have alot to be desired. That's what I did when learning OpenGL.

Comment: @stefan How do C# programmers Decide a particular library that suites a particular problem?

Comment: Sadly book recommendation are off topics on SO. Because it quickly turn into advertising. And with online course + YouTube tutorial + real book + "fake" book + blog post etc. the amount of material is too big to make a ranking of them.

Comment: `How do C# programmers Decide a particular library that suites a particular problem?` They Google for options and check NuGet download counts - as one example.

Comment: And the source code of the library is avaidable . So you could add the solution to your project, add a reference and press F12 every time you have a question about under the hood. https://github.com/CrazyRobMiles/snaps/tree/master/BeginToCodeWithCSharp/Snaps/Snaps .

Comment: @VictorEbhojie Deciding which library to take involves many things: How popular is a library? -> could indicate a good experience. How recently updated is it? -> if not very recent, it could mean the lib is abandoned, potentially insecure. Is the source code available? -> open source means you could fix bugs yourself, if necessary. Is it a reputable developer? -> You need to trust the developer, because the package could do arbitrary things. Does the library offer what I need? Ultimately, the library needs to deliver on its promises, have a good set of features, and hopefully few bugs.

Answer (score 5):

You might need to read about `Console` class.

for example:

```
Console.Write("Begin to Code With C#");
```

Will write a string in output for you.

Read more here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console?view=netcore-3.1

---

If you are in the beginning of the road to C#, I **highly** recommend you to take a look at these pages:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/intro-to-csharp/ ( Introduction to C# tutorials, which starts with interactive code that you can run in your browser)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/ (Very good resource to discover your path)
- https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/CSharp-Fundamentals-for-Absolute-Beginners (You can also start following Channel9 which is a great resource for learning.)
- https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/CSharp-101/ (Full Intro to C# video series by Scott Hanselman and Kendra Havens)
- https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/csharp (Here you can find many great C# learning videos by Scott Hanselman or other Microsoft professionals)

---

Following are some good C# learning books:

- [C# For Dummies](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764508148)
- [C# 8.0 and .NET Core 3.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07YLXFGBS)
- [Head First C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491976705)
- [C#: Learn C# in One Day and Learn It Well](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B016Z18MLG)
- [MCSD Certification Toolkit (Exam 70-483)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CP2PZB0)
- [Exam Ref 70-483 Programming in C#](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/exam-ref-70-483-programming-in-c-sharp-9781509306985)

---

**About Rob Miles Snaps**

> Firstly, I really wanted people to be able to do fun things (like make
> the computer talk, display graphics, take photographs, play sound
> effects and so on) right from the start. It turns out that this is
> rather tricky if you start from scratch, and so I thought some helper
> classes would be a good idea.

Reference: https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R2WHFW64MMXCS4/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=1509301151

> Snaps are an essential element of my “Begin to Code with C#” book, and
> if you can’t get them to work the book text doesn’t work very well

Reference: https://www.robmiles.com/journal/category/Snaps

Based on the abovementioned quotes from Rob Miles, I think this book **is not a good choice** for you. Because using this book, you have to learn two separate things: Learning C# and also Learning Rob Miles SNAP!

**NOTE**

I do not mean this is a good or bad book in overall. Just in your case, as it is confusing you, I THINK you need to change your learning material, or you might want to spend extra time to learn SNAP beside the C#.

Thanks to [@drag-and-drop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6560478/drag-and-drop), if you have decided to learn or explore the SNAP, you can take a look at its GitHub code: https://github.com/CrazyRobMiles/snaps

Comment: I think this answer is a bad representation of someone work. Reading [Author presentation](https://beta.iop.org/sites/default/files/2019-07/teaching-programming.pdf), it's clear that Snap is not a wrapper around `Console.Write`. Teaching programming is hard, I don't think this a bad book because he choose to add wrapper around many think. You can check the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/CrazyRobMiles/snaps/tree/master/BeginToCodeWithCSharp)

Comment: @DragandDrop I did not say it is a good or bad book in overall. But the method used in this book, just confused the question's author, so he needs to know and read more about SNAP beside reading about C#. If you reread my answer, I told I THINK...I mean this is my opinion that you can change the learning material, because the current one is confusing you, so this will lead to poor quality learning process.

Comment: Miss understanding , The display is not a Console.Write. Looking at the displayManager that expose  this method https://github.com/CrazyRobMiles/snaps/blob/master/BeginToCodeWithCSharp/Snaps/Snaps/XAMLSnaps/XAMLSnapsManager/DisplayManager.cs, you can see that it's a whole framework build as a sandbox. This code will be impossible to read for a beginner. The author presentation is usefull to understand the intented purpuse. But it's ok to disagree for example Imo 70-483 is not for beginner. Here the purpuse is to provide some "start to finish" exercise and not comprehension of the C# spec

Comment: @DragandDrop Talking with you is great. You are all right, but It seems that we have some contradictory opinions, which are very interesting for me. Author said: `I want to be able to display an out put without using a library`, so one way to achieve this goal is to use the `Console.Write`

Answer (score -2):

There is no need to use libraries to simply displaying output in c#.
Easiest and mostly used by all dot net/c# developer is `Console.Write("test")` or `Console.WriteLine("test")`.

Comment: How is this any different from the existing answer posted 40+ minutes ago?

Comment: I need them all, Everyone's contribution is welcome

Comment: Editing the existing answer is much better than commenting with the exact same answer.